# Plot ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, numerics, physics, parametric-functions

I am trying to plot the probability of a molecule being in a certain state via the numerical solution of the Schrödinger's equation of molecule in an oscillating electric field (in a rotating system).

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{2*I*a'[t] == -0.1*w*
     b[t]*(Exp[I*(0.1*w)*t] + Exp[-I*(2.1*w)*t]), 
   2*I*b'[t] == -0.1*w*
     a[t]*(Exp[-I*(0.1*w)*t] + Exp[I*(2.1*w)*t])}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 
   1000}, w]
```

Now I want to plot $|a(t)|^2$.

I tried this but it did not work:

```
Plot[Evaluate[Table[Abs[a[w][t]]^2 /. sol, {w, -1, 1, .1}]], {t, 0, 1000}, 
  PlotRange -> All]
```

Not sure where I made my mistake. Hope you can help!

Thank you very much!

Comment: Try using `(a /. sol)` instead of `a` and add initial conditions.

Comment: If you mean  `....Abs[(a /. sol)[w][t]]^2.... ` that does not work either.

Comment: My mistake about the replacement -- but if you try `a[1] /. sol` it should complain about the lack of initial conditions.

Comment: Won't you need initial conditions, eg. `a[0] == somevalue` and `b[0] == somevalue`?

Comment: Initial conditions! Good point. Nevertheless there are non given to me. If I assume that `a[0]== b[0]==0` my solution seems to be zero as well.

Comment: Set ´a[0] ==b[0] == 1` then use something like `f = a[3] /. sol` where 3 is the parameter value for w. You can then do `Plot[ Evaluate@Abs[ f[t] ]^2 , {t,0,100},PlotRange -> All ]`. Seems to work out fine.

Comment: I did exactly as you told me too. All I get is "General::noinfo: "Input expression InterpolatingFunction [{{0.,1000.}},<>] contains insufficient information to interpret the result.""

Answer (score 1):

Here is a short sketch of how I would do it. Since I am not a physicist this is more or less simply a *how to get a function plot* advice. ;-)

```
parSol = ParametricNDSolve[
  {
    2 I a'[t] == -0.1 w b[t] (Exp[ I (0.1 w) t] + Exp[-I (2.1 w) t]),
    2 I b'[t] == -0.1 w a[t] (Exp[-I (0.1 w) t] + Exp[ I (2.1 w) t]),
    (* initial conditions *)
    a[0] == b[0] == 1. (* or other initial values *)
  },
  (* vars *)
  { a, b },
  (* independent var *)
  { t, 0, 1000 },
  (* parameters *)
  w
];

ClearAll[funcPlot];
funcPlot[w_?NumericQ] := Module[
   {
     f, g
   },
   {f[t_], g[t_]} = Abs[#[t]]^2 & /@ ({a[w], b[w]} /. sol);
   Plot[
     Evaluate @{f[t], g[t]}, 
     {t, 0, 10}, 
     PlotTheme -> "Detailed", 
     PlotLegends -> {"a(t)", "b(t)"}
   ]
]
```

**Function Plot**

Here is what I get for `funcPlot[1.]`:

[image: Solution-Plots]

Answer (score 0):

Specifying initial conditions (as per gwr) resolves matters:

```
sol = ParametricNDSolve[{2*I*a'[t] == -0.1*w*
      b[t]*(Exp[I*(0.1*w)*t] + Exp[-I*(2.1*w)*t]), 
    2*I*b'[t] == -0.1*w*a[t]*(Exp[-I*(0.1*w)*t] + Exp[I*(2.1*w)*t]), 
    a[0] == b[0] == 1}, {a, b}, {t, 0, 1000}, w];
f[w_] := a[w] /. sol
Manipulate[Plot[Evaluate[Abs[f[w][t]]]^2, {t, 0, 1000}], {w, 0.1, 1}]
```

[image]